# WPF Tooltip dimensions not fitting content

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, styles, tooltip

I am having problems with a WPF Tooltip that am showing on validating a Textbox.  The tooltip that shows on mouse hover appears like a big rectangle and not wrapping the text.  I am using this style:

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Red" /> 
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a style for tooltip and add controltemplate with TextBlock. Do the textwraping in the TextBlock. Only thing is you may need to set MaxWidth for the tooltip

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="300" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  >
                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                </Style>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I did set the width manually but cant we bind it to the height of the TextBlock?  If am not mistaken, isnt the tooltip dimensions supposed to do that automatically?

Comment: In WPF if we are not mentioning any width or height text wraping it not possible. Same happens with the scrollbars.

Comment: I saw this blog and see that without setting the style, the tooltip is fine.  How is it doing so? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/princy.scorpin/data-validation-in-wpf-using-idataerrorinfo-and-displaying-t/

Comment: Oh is it?!  not fair.  Ok, then seems we will have to set its MaxWidth, MaxHeight